# Формирование отчета в Jenkins при параллельной сборке

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Есть такой проблема:
Существует несколько наборов автотестов и мне их нужно запускать выборочно, то одни, то другие. Для этого сделал в билде чекеры, чтобы можно было выбрать нужные. В пайплайне указано, что тесты идут параллельно, командами

```
 stash includes: 'target/allure-results/**', name: 'allure'
 stash includes: 'target/allure-results/**', name: 'allure1'
 stash includes: 'target/allure-results/**', name: 'allure2'
```

в каждом наборе тестов сохраняются отчеты, далее в блоке post командами

```
unstash 'allure'
unstash 'allure1'
unstash 'allure2'
```

эти отчеты извлекаются.

И всё работает, если указывать для прохождения все тесты. Но если какую-либо группу тестов пропустить (указать, данные тесты не должны идти), по ним соответственно не формируется отчет и команда unstash не может его извлечь и билд падает.

Как можно в блоке post указать условие для команды unstash или заключить ее в конструкцию try catch? Пробовал много вариантов, как это сделать, но рабочего варианта найти пока не получается

Answer (score 0):

Использовал catchError

```
 post {
        always {
            sh 'mvn clean'
            catchError {
                unstash 'allure1'
            }
            catchError {
                unstash 'allure2'
            }
```